# Hibernate, how to map wrapper classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mapping, wrapper

I'm writing a spring application and for my entities, I wanted to have some boundaries on the attributes by not using primitives but wrapper classes with methods.

So, instead of this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String title;

    public Event() {
    }
}
```

I want to have this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private Title title;

    public Event() {
    }
}
```

How do I tell hibernate to look inside of Title, which contains a single attribute `String title` with getters/setters and other methods? I tried using `@Embedded` but that messed up the JSON hierarchy.

Comment: If there is only one value (in this case title) you can use [AttributeConverter](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/)

Comment: Also a crunchy solution is to use @Embedded and @JsonUnwrapped to unwrapp your value in json. But `AttributeConverter` is a better solution of course.

Comment: So if my `Event` class had 8 wrappers, I'll have to create 8 more classes that implement `AttributeConverter`, damn?